# Opera in a C# application

Tags: c#, opera, toolbox

I have a C# application for on a pocket pc. It looks as a browser but some underlaying extra things. Currently im using the webbrowser of .net but I want to use the Opera browser due functionality. Is it possible to add a opera item on my form? And how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, Opera does not have an API that can be tapped into in order to embed their browser into an app.  I did some searching on Google, and didn't come up with anything.